# How to change Ubuntu Mate applications menu icon

Tags: icons, ubuntu-mate

I tried to look for it in the icon pack that I am using (Numix-Circle) but I could not find it. Where is this icon stored?

[image]

Comment: Would you explain more?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The icon is in `/usr/share/Numix/24/Places/start-here.png`. The same icon is different in Numix if the size is greater than 24.

- This is at size 24 [image: numix start here 24]
- This is at size 48 [image: numix start here 48]

Comment: Thanks! The icon wasn't in the exact place you mentioned, but it was close enough that I could find the icon (In case your wondering where the icon was, it was in /usr/share/icons/Numix/22/places).

Comment: Hmm. It's possible to have the icon in different places based on size. Anyway, glad to got it.